# Error in running fortran mpi program

Tags: mpi

After running MPI fortran program, I am getting error:

```
"Abort signaled by rank 2: No ACTIVE ports found
MPI process terminated unexpectedly
Abort signaled by rank 1: No ACTIVE ports found"
```

How to solve it?

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1016282 - do you have an Infiniband network?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I think I am not using infiniband network.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an MPI implementation compiled for Infiniband.  See here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=467532  Probably you need to find (or build) an MPI library for TCP.